# How to define a binding to a exclusive auto-delete queue from different connection?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to define a binding to a temporary queue from another client, but I get the following error:

```
405, "RESOURCE_LOCKED - cannot obtain exclusive access to locked queue 'amq.gen-z1cXo6IYh9G3YtYRazwKEw' in vhost '/'. It could be originally declared on another connection or the exclusive property value does not match that of the original declaration.
```

Obviously rabbitmq prevents me from defining a new binding to that queue from another connection, but I can't understand why. Is there a workaround or should I go for some other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use an exclusive queue, just use auto-delete.

Exclusive queues are just that - exclusive to the connection that declares them.